# How to compile curlpp on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, curl, compilation

Below is a simple test.c code using curl:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main(){        
    return 0;
}
```

To compile this code I use:

```
gcc test1.c -lcurl -o test1
```

For test1.c above compilation is correct. Now I would like to write some code using C++ libs (curlpp) and after that compile it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

To compile this code I tried:

```
g++ test2.cpp -lcurl -o test2
```

But I get this error:

```
fatal error: curlpp/cURLpp.hpp no such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This formula is not correct. The question is how to compile second code - test2.cpp?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to describe "it doesn't work" in more detail?

Comment: Simple: how to compile second code test2.cpp?

Comment: Did you get some sort of message telling you that it was not correct?

Comment: "fatal error: curlpp/cURLpp.hpp there are no such file or directory compilation terminated."

Answer (score 5):

You most likely forgot to install `libcurlpp-dev`.

You can find out where the required header files are located by running:

```
$ dpkg -S cURLpp.hpp
libcurlpp-dev:amd64: /usr/include/curlpp/cURLpp.hpp
```

Comment: "You most likely forgot to install libcurlpp-dev" -> how to install it? I tried "sudo apt-get install libcurlpp-dev" but I've got an information that there is no packet like this?

Comment: Please see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcurlpp-dev&searchon=names if you can find the package for your version of ubuntu.